# Integral with Fourier transform

Tags: analysis

Let $$f(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(-2\pi ixy)}{1+x^{2q}}dx $$
How using the fact that $f(y)$ is  Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{1+x^{2q}} $ to show that
 $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)x^{u}dx=0,\ u=1,...2q-1 $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: use these properties of Fourier transform ([106 here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships)), and inverse transform at $x=0$.

$$g(t)  \longleftrightarrow G(\omega) $$
$$ \hspace{58px} ? \;  \longleftrightarrow  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(\omega) d\omega $$
$$\hspace{28px} ? \; \longleftrightarrow  \omega^n G(\omega) $$